# Puzzle Piece html/css

Tags: html, css

I need to create a header that pieces can be easily added or removed based on the page being built and I'm having trouble with one part.

I have a header that looks like this will all components in

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hQDq2Wo.png]

and if the nav is removed it should adapt to look like this (vertically centered)

[image]

My question is how can I accomplish something like this in css. It also needs to work in IE8.

Comment: for fun try vertical-align on the div surrounding the nav and search and do middle. `vertical-align:middle` and see if that works. I'm curious if it will, but I don't know.

Comment: it looks like media queries question, but I'm not 100% as you've not mentioned how/why the nav will be removed.

Comment: How is your page being built?

Comment: @jbutler483 - Some pages are "campaign" pages and don't require a nav as they are for promo only. The search bar may even be removed too.

Comment: @Duffmaster33 manually built by a developer but the css must be smart enough to adapt based on a a guideline I have to make.

Comment: @Luca I meant how is the page rendered.  If you just have static pages then you can create whatever rules you would like on each page.  For instance, header 1 has class nav and header 2 does not in order to differentiate

Comment: @Duffmaster33 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by how are they rendered. Static HTML in most cases

Comment: @Luca all you said was sometimes this header will have a nav bar and sometimes it won't.  There are potentially hundred of different ways your pages could be rendered (wordpress or other CMS, Java servlet or JSP, FreeMarker, Angular just to name a couple of the bigger ones) or they could be static.  If they are static, then there is no dynamic nature to it so the answer is you have full control over what is on the screen in regards to HTML structure and CSS.  Unless you have some specific need that is not clear from your question, in which case code example would be very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for.
Now you can change its positions or remove them and add or remove buttons from nav bar.
But remember that you must keep some spacing standards to achieve a good design, so, obviously you will need to change the heights and maybe add some paddings/margins. Be aware that each border fills 1px of the total header's height

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="navWrap">
        <input type="search" class="nav-search">  
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li>Apps</li>
            <li>Games</li>
            <li>Movies</li>
            <li>Books</li>
            <li>Newspapers</li>
        </ul>
   </div>
```

```
.header,
.nav-list{
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -moz-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.header{
    height: 120px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px black;
    align-items: center;
}

.navWap{
    height: inherit;
}

.nav-search,
.nav-list {
    width: 700px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.nav-list ~ .nav-search,
.nav-search ~ .nav-list{
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.nav-list > li{
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow:1;
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-right: none;
}

.nav-list > li:last-child{
    border-right: solid 1px black;
}
```

Working here:

http://codepen.io/EderIraizoz/pen/EaBgWg